# Python urllib encoded url has an extra character

Tags: python, url, urllib, urlencode

I am trying to encode this list from python's urllib.

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlencode, unquote
>>> data_to_encode = {'user_ids': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> encoded_url = urlencode(data_to_encode)
>>> 
>>> encoded_url
'user_ids=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D'
>>>
>>> unqoute(encoded_url)
'user_ids=[1,+2,+3]'
```

The encoding is inserting an extra `+` sign with the elements. Why is it happening and how can I resolve this, so that my url before encoding and after decoding is same?

Comment: Because `urlencode` encodes spaces to `+`, but unquote only replaces `%..` sequences back to characters, not `+` to spaces. — What did you expect instead? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @deceze there are no leading spaces on the numbers.

I have had a play around and get this:

```>>> data_to_encode = {'user_ids':['1','2','3']}
>>> encoded_url = urlencode(data_to_encode)
>>> unquote(encoded_url)
"user_ids=['1',+'2',+'3']"
>>> ```

Comment: @James Not sure what you're trying to say. A `repr` of the list gets encoded, i.e. `[1, 2, 3]` is turned into the string `'[1, 2, 3]'`, which contains spaces, which are encoded to `+`.

Comment: I got there in the end with that - hopefully my answer explains where the + are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `__str__` method of list returns the item in the list joined by `", "` which is a comma followed by a space. When you pass the list `[1,2,3]` to urlencode it is implicitly calling the `__str__` method to get the string representations.

```
>>> data_to_encode['user_ids'].__str__()
"[1, 2, 3]"
>>> ['apple','orange','pear'].__str__()
"['apple', 'orange', 'pear']"
```

You could try [unquote_plus](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_plus)

> urllib.parse.unquote_plus(string, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
> Like unquote(), but also replace plus signs with spaces, as required
> for unquoting HTML form values.